# How to access a variable outside an event handler when it is defined within the event handler in c#?

Tags: c#, user-interface, global-variables, windows-forms-designer, eventhandler

Below is some of my code in a c# windows forms application.

It assigns a random Integer to handle. How can I access the new value of handle so it can be used by other function calls outside this button event since there is no global variables in c#?

I've tried using a Method but it still wont recognise handle when I call it outside the button event.

Also what would I use to make my GUI that you cannot use some of the other controls until this button is pressed?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Int handle = 0;
      random(ref handle);
    }
```

Comment: You can't, so why define it in the scope of the event handler if you want to access it outside this scope. If it we defined as a field/class level variable then you could access it from elsewhere.

Comment: If its about accessing the handle anywhere in class then declare it as class level variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public class MyClass
    {
            private int handle;

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                handle = 0;
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                GetHandle();
            }

            private int GetHandle()
            {
                return handle;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming I have misunderstood your question, but in case you've missed the obvious. How does this look?

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private int _handle;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _handle = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways.

1. Define a member, use member.
2. Build an event, send that variable out use that event triggered inside this event. This is equal to you calling the function need this variable directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class-level variable and use it to store this value.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Int _handle = 0;

    private void incrementHandle()
    {
        _handle++;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        random(ref handle);
    }

    ...
}
```